# Restrict text area in css

Tags: html, css, text, margin

I tried to restrict the area where I can write text on my website.

```
<div id="header">
<div id="text"> 
     sample text 
</div>
</div>
```

When I try to write many characters in `text`, there is no line break when the given space is exceeded.

```
#header
{
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 100px;

}

#text
{
 margin-left: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
#text
{
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;  
}​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/bwZKe/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to perform word-wrapping, the following will work.

```
#text{ 
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* Most modern browsers */       
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* older versions of Opera */   

}
```

The `word-wrap` property isn't limited to newer browsers only. Older browsers seem to support it as well.

From the CSS3 draft,

> For legacy reasons, certain experimental CSS properties do not follow
>   this prefixing convention. Two common examples are the ‘word-wrap’ and
>   ‘text-overflow’ properties, which were introduced unprefixed by
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer prior to the introduction of the vendor
>   prefixing policy in CSS2.1 and were subsequently implemented
>   unprefixed by other browsers, creating a dependency on the unprefixed
>   names despite the lack of a W3C spec.

See article [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/) and [w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/).

Comment: Isn´t there another possibility without css3?

Comment: It isn't limited to CSS3. See [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/). I have edited my answer.

Comment: @user896692 I think the problem is because you add one long word. If you use multiple words it gets a line break. You can give HTML soft hyphen a look or the HTML `wbr` tag if you use long words.